# SQL Join - giving me multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get unique values of LINE_NO. I am trying to understand what's wrong in code.

```
SELECT SHIPMENT_TAB.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, SHIPMENT_TAB.SHIP_VIA_CODE, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_ADDR_ID, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_ADDRESS_NAME, SHIPMENT_TAB.SHIPMENT_ID, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_ID,
SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_COUNTRY, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_ADDRESS1, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_ADDRESS2, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_CITY, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_STATE, SHIPMENT_TAB.RECEIVER_ZIP_CODE,
SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB.SOURCE_REF1, SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB.SOURCE_PART_NO, SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB.CONNECTED_SOURCE_QTY, SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB.SOURCE_UNIT_MEAS,
CUSTOMER_ORDER_TAB.CUSTOMER_PO_NO, CUSTOMER_ORDER_TAB.AUTHORIZE_CODE, CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_TAB.ORDER_NO, CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_TAB.LINE_NO, TI_PART_EXT_CLV.CF$_PATTERN_SHADE,
TI_PART_EXT_CLV.CF$_PART_NO, TI_PART_EXT_CLV.CF$_STYLE_NO, TI_PART_EXT_CLV.CF$_FINISHED_WIDTH, part_catalog_tab.description
from SHIPMENT_TAB join SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB on SHIPMENT_TAB.SHIPMENT_ID = SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB.SHIPMENT_ID 
JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER_TAB on SHIPMENT_LINE_TAB.SOURCE_REF1 = CUSTOMER_ORDER_TAB.ORDER_NO
JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_TAB on CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_TAB.ORDER_NO = CUSTOMER_ORDER_TAB.ORDER_NO
JOIN TI_PART_EXT_CLV on TI_PART_EXT_CLV.CF$_PART_NO = CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_TAB.PART_NO
JOIN PART_CATALOG_TAB on PART_CATALOG_TAB.PART_NO = TI_PART_EXT_CLV.CF$_PART_NO
WHERE SHIPMENT_TAB.SHIPMENT_ID = 42;
```

This code should give me output of 3 values. Based on SHIPMENT_LINE TAB.SHIPMENT_LINE_NO i.e 1,4,2.

But I am getting 1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4.
Getting 9 shows that it is not giving me exact 3 rows as the output.

Comment: Please format your code properly so that it is readable. Also why do you say the code is wrong?

Comment: Obviously, join between tables arent unique. i suggest you to join 1 table at a time and see where its causing dups

Comment: Okay let me try that.